# how to solve could not find com.adroid.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha04?

Tags: android, gradle

I try to upgrade my android version from 2.3 to 3.0,  but when i try to open one of my project there are some error displayed.

[image]

i try to sync it but still display the same error.

Comment: put your gradle files

Comment: Why are you trying to use an alpha build plugin? Did you copy your Gradle file from somewhere?

Comment: no, i don't. But when i update, my android studio suggest me to download from this link https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html?utm_source=android-studio . i'm following the instructions given.